# How to debug a simulated browser client of socket.io in node.js server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have simulated a browser client of socket.io  in the node.js server

I am creating the simulated browser client when particular message arrived from a Real browser client.

```
     console.log('creating client of '+sessionId);
    var socket=client.init();

    console.log(socket);
```

here is my Simulated browser client in node.js , I am using https://github.com/saschagehlich/node-socket.io-client for creating client.

```
exports.init=function(){
    var socket = new io.Socket(config.host, {port: config.port, rememberTransport: false});
    // when connected, clear out display
    socket.on('connect',function() {
        console.log('dummy user connected');
    });
    socket.on('disconnect',function() {
        console.log('disconnected dummy');
    });
    socket.on('message', function(data){
      console.log(data);
    });
    socket.connect();
    return socket;
};
```

The problem is this that the consoles in the client is not getting printed , the socket is return and printed . but not console. in client code.
And i also want the session id of simulated client , how can i get it ?

Comment: problem was in my declaration of config , not given the var , now its running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js has a simple debugger that can be invoked using:

`node debug script.js`

The debugger has simple commands like `print` or `step`. You could write code inline and use `util.inspect()` for inspecting objects.

Something more advanced would be using Google's V8 debugger http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/DebuggerProtocol
but that's usually an overkill...

Comment: I tried this but not going in client http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.7/api/debugger.html#advanced_Usage

Comment: Did you use the `debugger;` phrase to place breakpoints? Have you placed various log prints? What exactly is called and what isn't?